# Does Collection.SynchronizedList iterator block entire iteration process or just .next() part?

Tags: java, iterator, synchronizedcollection

Before I ask anything you might tell me to read docs. But I am still a beginner and I am not handling docs so easily. My question is does iterator in `SynchronizedList` block 'entire iteration process (loop)' or just its methods?

Meaning: Can another thread do some work on `synchronizedList` **instance** while iteration is 'going on'? Or it can do some work after thread that called `next()`, as I noticed `next()` is also synchronized.

I would appreciate any help, thanks :)

Comment: Just its methods. There is no way for the class to detect if it is being used in a loop.

Comment: So that means I can add items to a list from one thread, while one is iterating? That looks kinda bad..

Answer (score 0):

> does iterator in SynchronizedList block 'entire iteration process (loop)' or just its methods?

Just its methods.

There is no way for the class to detect if it is being used in a loop.

If you need the list to be synchronised for the entirety of a loop, externally synchronize on the list:

```
synchronized (list) {
  for (E element : list) { ... }
}
```

Comment: But that still doesn't mean other thread can't modify list. I checked implementation of basic methods, they have their own keys, meaning this won't work, will it? As your synchronized block uses different key..

Comment: @AnaMaria have you looked at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))?

Comment: Yes. For example: public void add() uses synchronized (Vector.this). And you used list as a key. Meaning this won't work. As they are locked to 2 different keys

Comment: @AnaMaria I mean: the Javadoc says this works, so if the version of the JDK you are using is written in a way such that this doesn't work, it's an incorrect implementation. Please provide details of which JDK/version you see "Vector.this" in, because I don't see it in the versions I'm looking at.

Comment: Actually it is quite new (11.0.04) is my SDK. Yes in Vector methods are synchronized on Vector.this, while on SynchronizedList they are synchronized on final Object mutex; I kinda don't know how synchronizing on list in your case would help us unless we use same keys as internal implementation..

Comment: @AnaMaria have a look at what the value of `mutex` is.